# What is the speed of a baud rate? - RN42

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, baudrate, modem

After wondering/researching about this for days, I finally ask this question: What is the speed (bits per second) of a bluetooth SPP RN-42 device? Is 1 baud = 1 bit (thus 9600 baud = 9600 bits per second) or 1 baud = 1 packet (9600 baud = approx. 9600 * 8 bits = 96000 bits per second)?

The data sheet says: "Sustained SPP data rates: 240 Kbps (Slave mode), 300 Kbps (Master mode)" but do they mean BAUD per second or BIT/BYTE per second?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In general, the lower case b is bits while the upper case B is bytes. So "240 Kbps" is 240,000 **bits** per second. BAUD represents the number of **symbols** per second which depends on how the signal is modulated. However, for a simple serial signal, it generally corresponds directly to bits per second.

Comment: This may help you: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56265/difference-between-hz-and-bps/56270#56270

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking 1 Baud means one symbol per second.  A symbol may represent more than one bit.

Most people however use Baud rate and bits per second (bps) interchangeably.

Comment: I was aware that 1 baud represents 1 symbol/sec. However I wasn't sure if the RN42 data sheet meant baud = symbol or just baud = bit. But now I guess they meant bit per second...